# If all columns say "Complete" move to sheet2 else move to sheet3

Tags: arrays, string, vba, find, move

I need help with my code. The logic is: if they all say "complete" then copy the first line of code to sheet 2. If one says something besides "complete" copy it to sheet 3. It may have more than one line that says something beside "complete". I have a web_scraper flashing this area with data and I need to sort it. The IMAGE included is basically what the data will look like. Also the complete has (3) spaces after it, so I've included it in my code.

[image]

```
    Sub test()

Dim P, lastrow4
lastrow4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For P = 1 To lastrow4

'****if complete****
'if row one is complete and row 2 is blank place in sheet 2


If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P, "A").Value = "COMPLETE   " And Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P + 1, "A").Value = "" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(P, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If


****/if not complete*********************

'if row 1 isn't complete and is not blank put in sheet 5


If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P, "J").Value <> "COMPLETE   " And Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P, "J").Value <> "" Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(P, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End If

Next P

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions below, but some of your code is unclear, like offset needs 2 values .offset(1,0).  You also use Rows.count- which rows are you applying that too?  all in the worksheet?  you need to use Range("A1:A2").Rows.Count for example.

Ive corrected your dimensioning, and changed a range/cells reference that was confused, but you need to make this into something more understandable before it can be properly corrected.

see here for a good starting point with cell references

**http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html**

```
Sub test()

Dim P as long, lastrow4 as long
lastrow4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For P = 1 To lastrow4
'****if complete****
'if row one is complete and row 2 is blank place in sheet 2

If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P, 1).Value = "COMPLETE   " And Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(P, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If


'****/if not complete*********************
'if row 1 isn't complete and is not blank put in sheet 5


If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P, "J").Value <> "COMPLETE   " And Sheets("sheet1").Cells(P, "J").Value <> "" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(P, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next P

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Im new to vba so my coding may not be typical. But i'll explain my thought process. The offset doesn't need two values, if only one is entered it assumes you want to offset by row. And my rows.count is referencing the last column, that is because my actual last cell changes so i can't say a1:a2, so im using xlUP to go up from the bottom row to find my last cell.  But i figured it out, i needed to use a Boolean variable to return a true or false. So i set it to put it in sheet1. if true leave it, and check remaining values. If false copy to sheet2 and delete from sh1

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't actually dealing w/ sheet 1 & 2 I just changed that for help. This works for row 15 down from sheet 2, and moved to sheet 4 if true sheet 5 is false

```
Dim P, lastrow4
P = 15
lastrow4 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim check As Boolean

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastrow4, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                For P = 15 To lastrow4
                    check = Sheets("sheet2").Range("J" & P) = "COMPLETE   "
                    If check = False Then
                        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(P, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet5").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        Sheets("sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If

                Next P
```